# How to read an java swing thread, event completion status from command promt

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My application is developed on java swing technology and we are trying to automate it using commercial tools build on windows and dlls, but the tool was not able to wait till all the swing event/worker threads complete processing... I have a need go to read and monitor the my application thread/event process completion status before moving to next operation ?

Please help me in some sample code to read swing application process from another jar/ from command prompt

In simple words, how to read java swing application thread/process completion status from another java program? we are using [github.com/vivekprahlad/frankenstein](https://github.com/vivekprahlad/frankenstein) to automate our application ... this has very less documentation on how to start application and execute tests ...

I am intermediate to eclipse and java programs ... all we are trying is to automate unit test cases using frankenstein.. Need help on how to start with sample code ... 1. How to start my application from frankenstein, my application will start from a bat file, I added 'com.thoughtworks.frankenstein.application.PipingMain com.abc.app.tone.all.Launcher' to bat file, so that frankenstein recorder will open and was able to record actions. But want to write a test in eclipse and execute ..

Comment: I'm not sure about the others, but I'm very confused about your requirements and problems. Consider clarifying your question by providing more detail and explanation and possibly some pertinent code, preferably a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if that's possible.

Comment: In simple words, how to read java swing application thread/process completion status from another java program? we are using https://github.com/vivekprahlad/frankenstein to automate our application ... this has very less documentation on how to start application and execute tests ...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I am intermediate to eclipse and java programs ... all we are trying is to automate unit test cases using frankenstein..  Need help on how to start with sample code ... 1. How to start my application from frankenstein, my application will start from a bat file, I added 'com.thoughtworks.frankenstein.application.PipingMain com.abc.app.tone.all.Launcher' to bat file, so that frankenstein recorder will open and was able to record actions. But want to write a test in eclipse and execute ..

Comment: Why don't you use VC++ for this? and if using java is very important, why are you destroying the language's **WORA** principle?

Comment: @NabeelOmer Didn't get your comment, how does VC++ would solve my issue ? or will it automate java swing applications ? if yes any tool suggestions you have ?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to make your `SwingWorker` background task separately testable. Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513), set an appropriate `exit()` status in the implementation of `done()`. In the example below, the code is marked successful, `0` by convention, if the calculated value is within a defined tolerance.

Command line:

```
$ java -cp build/classes Test ; echo $?
1.4142135623730951
0
```

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    /** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513 */
    private static class TwoWorker extends SwingWorker<Double, Double> {

        private static final int N = 5;
        double x = 1;

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                x = x - (((x * x - 2) / (2 * x)));
                setProgress(i * (100 / N));
                publish(x);
            }
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Double> chunks) {
            for (double d : chunks) {
                //…
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.exit((Math.abs(x - Math.sqrt(2))) < 0.00001 ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TwoWorker().execute();
    }
}
```